# how to improve JavaScript runtime

Tags: javascript, runtime

im solved this question on leetcode.com(https://leetcode.com/problems/contains-duplicate/) and the problem is my runtime was 6205ms which is very bad because 69% of users solved it with 86ms i tried a few things but nothing worked i searched but there was nothing i could do i really could use some help and explaining

```js
let dupes = []
    for(let i=0; i<nums.length; i++){
        if(!dupes.includes(nums[i])){
            dupes.push(nums[i])
        }
    }
    return !(dupes.length == nums.length)
```

Comment: Make `dups` a `Set` instead of array.

Comment: `Array.includes()` is O(n), so your algorithm is O(n^2).

Comment: first of all whats a ```set```, secondly what am i supposed to use instead of ```includes()```

Comment: [The Set object lets you store unique values of any type, whether primitive values or object references.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Comment: Did you make any attempt to learn this on your own? Like google "javascript set"?

Comment: i searched up its prototypes and made the ```dupes``` a set and the runtime dropped to 76ms thank you so much, so ```includes()``` is bad ??

Comment: sorry i was a bit lazy i thought it was something complicated

Comment: can i put the edited code as an answer and close the question ?

Comment: Yes, you can answer your own question.

Comment: `includes()` isn't bad when the arrays are small. But LeetCode deliberately uses large amounts of data so you have to find a more optimal algorithm.

Comment: If you are seeing if there is any dupes there is no reason to keep looping after you find a dupe.

Comment: `console.log(new Set(nums).size !== nums.length)` or `const lookup = {}; console.log(nums.some(n => lookup[n] ? 1 : (lookup[n] = 1, 0)));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so as Barmar said in his comments i changed the array `dupes` to a set and changed `includes` to `has()`, `length` to `size` and `push()` to `add()` this is the code`

```js
let dupes = new Set()
for(let i=0; i<nums.length; i++){
    if(!dupes.has(nums[i])){
        dupes.add(nums[i])
    }
}
return !(dupes.size == nums.length)
```

Comment: There is no need to check if a set has a value before adding. Sets already already contain unique values, so all you need is `let dupes = new Set(nums)` without the loop.

Comment: Also `!(dupes.size == nums.length)` is an unorthodox way to express inequality, as opposed to `a != b`

Comment: what is "an unorthodox way" and what do you suggest and why ?

Comment: Unorthodox means not usual. I suggest using an actual inequality operator `!=` or `!==` instead of negating the result of equality. The why is because it's *not* unorthodox but the usual way inequality is expressed.